# check for null value in MS Access SQL statement

Tags: sql, ms-access

The following query is not returning values for `CurrentVisitor` in my ms access 2010 database:

```
SELECT h.ClientNumber, IIf(h.CheckoutDate=null,"Yes","") AS CurrentVisitor 
FROM VisitsTable AS h 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ClientNumber, MAX(LastVisitDate) AS LastVisitStart 
    FROM VisitsTable 
    GROUP BY ClientNumber)  
    AS t 
ON (h.LastVisitStart = t.LastVisitStart) AND (h.ClientNumber = t.ClientNumber);
```

I think the reason is that the check for null in the `If()` operation is not written correctly.  Can anyone show me how to fix this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use

```
Is Null
```

rather than

```
= Null
```

Comment: +1.  And credit for the answer.  Thank you for the quick and correct response.

Comment: `IIf(IsNull(...), ..., ...)` would have been the more traditional way to do it, but if `Is Null` works then who am I to quibble?

Comment: @GordThompson - why do you say 'more traditional'? Unless things have changed, 'Something Is Null' is pure SQL, 'IsNull(Something)' (in a JET context) VBA, and it's always better to use pure SQL if you can.

Comment: `IIf()` is already fairly specific to Access SQL and VB* (compare with `CASE ... WHEN ...` in T-SQL) so `IsNull()` is how old timers like me would tend to write it. But like I said, "If it works..." (and I've already upvoted your answer).

Comment: @GordThompson - sure, we're dealing with Access SQL, but that still doesn't impact my preference for Is Null over IsNull (that's why I put 'in a JET context'). Moreover, the Access SQL IIf is different from the Access VBA IIf, as I expect you know (the SQL one short circuits, the VBA one - rather annoyingly - doesn't).